# Suppressing a MatPlotLib benign warning

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, legend

I'm plotting a few different graphs, and I don't want to have a legend since I don't need it.

```
ax.scatter(x, y, ..., label='')
```

The above works just fine for me, but it sends a UserWarning out. 
I know it's benign and doesn't actually affect the program at all, but I'd like to find a way to not have it.

I know you can suppress all warnings in python, but I just want to suppress this specific warning.

Oh and removing `label=''` still makes the warning.

Thank in advance

Comment: The line `ax.scatter(x, y, label='')` alone **does not** produce a warning. You are having something else in your code that is responsible for the warning. Please show the warning istself and a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can suppress all warnings:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

or you can suppress specific warnings like this:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore",category=matplotlib.cbook.mplDeprecation)
```

Comment: Ah thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Rather than suppressing a warning you should remove the cause of the warning.

Comment: from what I understood the warning is caused by the absence of a label, if he doesn't want the label I suppress the warning. And the question was about how to suppress a warning, so you should not downvote my answer anyway.  @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: I downvoted because if you interprete the question as asking for how to suppress a warning, this question has already been asked before and already has an answer. Answering duplicate questions only makes sense if the answer is more specific than any duplicate.